# Applying to Ph.D. programs in history when my degree is in a science field

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I would like to apply for Ph.D. programs in history, but I am a graduate of a science program. Do I need another degree in order to apply to history Ph.D. programs?

Comment: Can you provide any more details?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your institution, but most likely, yes you will need to have a certain undergraduate background. History is a field that requires a background, and this will be needed for PhD studies. Nevertheless, as you do have a science degree, I believe that there are programs that will accept you into terminal M.S. programs where you can then apply for a PhD. My advice - look around, email faculty, and apply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.  It depends on the institution. You must read the doctoral notice (rules).
But, above all, you must think what is your purpose doing that. Be aware that you will have more difficulty doing a PhD in a new issue and if it's worth, if you want a career in this new area.